# remove whitespace from html document using ruby

Tags: html, xml, ruby

So I have a string in ruby that is something like

```
str = "<html>\n<head>\n\n  <title>My Page</title>\n\n\n</head>\n\n<body>" +
      "  <h1>My Page</h1>\n\n<div id=\"pageContent\">\n  <p>Here is a para" +
      "graph. It can contain  spaces that should not be removed.\n\nBut\n" +
      "line breaks that should be removed.</p></body></html>"
```

How would I remove all whitespace (spaces, tabs, and linebreaks) that is outside of a tag/not inside a tag that has content like `<p>` using only native Ruby?

(I'd like to avoid using XSLT or something for a task this simple.)

Comment: Your html isn't correct. You have one open <p> tag and two closing </p>.

Comment: .. and a spurious, unmatched `</body>` tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
str.gsub!(/\n\t/, " ").gsub!(/>\s*</, "><")
```

That first `gsub!` replaces all line breaks and tabs with spaces, the second removes spaces between tags.

You will end up with multiple spaces inside your tags, but if you just removed all `\n` and `\t`, you would get something like "not be removed.Butline breaks", which is not very readable. Another Regular Expression or the aforementioned `.squeeze(" ")` could take care of that.

Comment: I'm no regex guru, but I needed to use `/(\n|\t|\r)/` in place of `/\n\t/` to accomplish this. My final regex was `str.gsub(/(\n|\t|\r)/, ' ').gsub(/>\s*</, '><').squeeze(' ')`

Comment: People are saying bad things about using regex on html: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/165673

Comment: @Yarin That answer is generally correct.  Using regular expressions to manipulate HTML often leads to suffering.

Answer (score 7):

Hate to split hairs about regexen, but none of the other answers are strictly correct. This will work:

```
str.gsub(/>\s*/, ">").gsub(/\s*</, "<")
```

Explicitly converting newlines is unnecessary because `/\s/` matches all whitespace characters including newline. The regexen in the other answers are not strictly correct because their regexen fail to match `"\r"`, which is used at the end of lines in Windows and will appear in emails.

My line will also convert `<p>   foo  bar  </p>` into `<p>foo  bar</p>`, but you may not want this.

Comment: This will result in spaces being eliminated in undesirable places. For example, if there is an `a` tag inside of text it will render without spaces.

Comment: Good catch. To give an example, "foo <a> foo</a>" becomes "foo<a>foo</a>". Sorry, in that case I don't see a reliable way of doing this with regexes.

I suppose you could match every tag that doesn't have default style "display: inline", but then if someone overrides this in CSS, then it breaks your regex.

Comment: Furthermore, you'd need to match the "end of a tag with one of a set of names" and this would be basically impossible

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I don't think there's a reasonable way to do this without traversing the document with an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can condense all groups of space characters into one space (ie, `hello   world` into `hello world`) by using String#squeeze:

```
"hello     world".squeeze(" ")  # => "hello world"
```

Where the parameter of squeeze is the character to be squeezed.

EDIT: I misread your question, sorry.

This would

- remove consecutive spaces within tags
- leave individual spaces outside tags

I'll work on a solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
xml.squish.gsub /(> <)/, '><'
```

Even shorter than above.

PS I love the funny faces.